# Customer data are encrypted

Tags: customer, customer-attribute, encryption-key

When open Admin Panel -> Customers most of the attributes are encoded like this: "ad05fac20be580518ea1f5163f21a063". Hex strings.

Any idea where this comes from and how can I decrypt it?
I have used `Enterprise_Pci_Encryption -> decrypt()` but don't get correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Customer informations are per default not encrypted. What is encrypted are credit card data. Therefore I assume either you have a module which does this or even worse a virus.